# Can't make String equal method and Converting Strings to Numbers work together.

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

It is a Java beginner question. The program is not complicated, it just asks the user input grade and then finish it when the user input "y" , and then calculate max, min,average, and total.

My trouble is that I can't stop the loop when I type y. Thank you so much, if anyone can help me out. I have tried many approaches to figure that.

```
    do
       { 
        System.out.println("please go on");
        input = keyboard.next();                    
        grade = Integer.parseInt(input);
        InputTimes++;
        if (grade>Maxgrade)
        {   
            Maxgrade = grade;       
         }

        if(Mingrade>grade)
        {
            Mingrade= grade;            
        }

        if (input.equals("y"))
        {   
            GameOver = true;
            System.out.println("yyyyyyy");
            break;
        }   
        else 
        {
            GameOver = false;
            System.out.println("nnnnnn");   
        }   
        totalgradeNoF = grade+totalgradeNoF;

    }while(GameOver==false);
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: if you enter `y` then it will throw exception when executing `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: while(!input.contains("y")); give condition like this way in your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int Maxgrade = 0, Mingrade = 0, InputTimes = 0, grade = 0, totalgradeNoF = 0;
boolean GameOver = false;
String input = "";
do {
    System.out.println("Please go on : ('y' to stop)");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("y")) {
        GameOver = true;
    } else {
        grade = Integer.parseInt(input);
        InputTimes++;

        if (grade > Maxgrade) {
             Maxgrade = grade;
        }
        if (Mingrade > grade) {
             Mingrade = grade;
        }

        totalgradeNoF = grade + totalgradeNoF;
   }
} while (!GameOver);
```

Some things to change :

- You need to check the "y" BEFORE and if it is not a "y" so you can cast to int
- You don"t need to use `break`so
- You may use `!GameoOver` instead of `GameOver==false`
- Don't need to set `Gameover=false` at each iteration, just at the initialisation

Comment: appreciate it, in the beginning, I thought java can automatically ignore my input which is not number. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

When you enter 'y' NumberFormatException is coming, so you need to handle this exception and then you can exit from the loop after typing 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

Use for Scanner methods `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` for reading input.

EX:-

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

then we can use `scan.nextInt()` for get int

and we can use `scan.nextLine()` for get Strings

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm
this link may be help for you.

sorry for my english.